# Can I remove "More Videos" from an embedded YouTube player using CSS class selectors?

Tags: css, iframe, youtube, embed

I work in a school library, and I'm trying to get rid of the "More Videos" popup from my embedded YT videos as we would much prefer for students to not be accessing irrelevant or inappropriate content from an in-house resource. I know that the "rel=0" parameter doesn't work anymore, since 2018 (even though tons of "helpful" videos still cite this as a solution) so after trawling through tons of search results I decided to try just disabling the popup through CSS.

I'm no expert on CSS by any means but I've been learning a lot as I go - I've inspected the source code of the player and located the relevant class selectors. I have successfully hidden the pause popup, which is definitely a big step - however when I try to do the same for the "end of video" popup, my custom CSS is totally ignored. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and what I can do (if anything) to achieve what I want?

I'm working in LibGuides, which allows me to place `<style>` tags in the area where I paste the YT embed code. Inside the style tag I've just put

```
.ytp-pause-overlay-container {display: none;}
```

to hide the pause popup, which works great; but

```
.videowall-endscreen {display: none;}
```

does nothing, it doesn't even appear in the inspector console at all. I've tried multiple different class selectors, as the div in question has several assigned to it, but I get the same result. It seems like the fact that the YT player is in an iframe might be a reason for the problem - but if that's the case, why does the pause overlay code work?

I'm at my wits' end here - any assistance would be fantastic and much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. This is a great question and I wondered myself about this too. However I already failed at step 1, the pause overlay, since I have no control about the sources INSIDE the IFrame. Can you elaborate a bit about this LibGuides stuff?`

Comment: Hi Marcel - LibGuides is a subscription service from a company called Springshare, that provides a platform for libraries (and possibly other institutions) to create websites, generally in the form of study guides for students and that sort of thing. So you can choose from preset layouts and add various elements to the pages, like rich text, embedded widgets, etc. But they are also quite customisable if you know your way around CSS and/or JavaScript.

Comment: So in terms of my hiding the pause overlay - I simply added the CSS code I mentioned inside the same area where I paste the YT embed code, which is in a "Add Content" popup on the LibGuides page. So maybe that gives me some extra reach with the code? I really don't have the knowledge or understanding to that level of things so I can't explain it. I wish I knew why the end-of-video stuff won't work though!

Comment: Update: Apparently the embed URL also needs the "?rel=0" for the CSS code to work? I'm confused but that's nothing new for me when it comes to this stuff.